# Is RavenDB 3.0 backwards compatible with 2.0 Clients?

Tags: ravendb

I can't seem to find this information anywhere. The 2.5 docs have a backwards compatibility page, but the 3.0 pages do not.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have run a 2.5 client against the 3.0 database and everything seems to work. I would like to get an official answer on this though.

In case anyone wants to know: the 3.0 client does not seem to work against a 2.5 server.